# Gas pipe behind gutter, causing water damage on facia

Tags: gas, waterproofing, exterior, gutters

During a room addition long ago, gas line was rerouted to travel through addition, then along facia toward furnace. Because it travels behind gutter, water rides behind the gutter in some spots along that stretch. The facia board needs replaced.

Do I have the pipe moved downward (by a plumber?) so that gutter can be next to facia?

Or do I live with the pipe as is, and replace wood with cement board so it will last longer?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear how the water is getting there. At any rate, wood fascias rot regardless of what's over them. I'd replace it with inexpensive boards and wrap it with steel.

Comment: @isherwood - thanks, i added another image, showing the gap between facia and back of gutter. Separates in areas where there is not a hanger. Water travels over edge of shingles and down the venting. I've tried adding drip edge in some places, but distance between roof edge and gutter is too short in some areas.

Comment: Obviously the drip edge isn't doing its job. I'd look at a small flashing extension to remedy that. I've used 45 degree angle to do that.

Comment: The pipe itself appears to be getting rather rusty, partially from being outside and partially from being kept moist behind the gutter. You might want to consider that now is the time to "do it right", replacing the gutter and fascia (as necessary) _and_ rerouting the gas line to a better location. Of course, iron pipe outside _will_ rust, but if it's where you can get to it easier, it's easier to maintain a coat of paint that will protect it.

Comment: With that light showing I would say even with the board replaced there will still be a problem,  I don’t think the pipe relocation will solve the leak.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom flashing that goes under the starter course of shingles and protrudes further out and down into the gutter. You are correct saying that the roof edge is too short.
A local gutter guy and or roofer should easily be able to help for very little money. Plus in one of the pictures I see some sort of a flashing on top of the roofing maybe a chimney? That could be the source of your problem as well.
If you own this home I’d highly suggest asking around for a creative and honest roofer